# How to force latex to neccesarily put a mathematical expression in a single line?

Tags: math-mode

I'm writing a game theory book, and I've wrote something like this:

[image]

As it can be seen, that mathematical expression has been splited into two lines. It surely can be fixed, by making some spaces' width more, and if needed, leaving a little space for the expression to appear in the next line, as latex sometimes does. How can I force it automatically do it when needed?

Comment: What exactly is your beef with the line break, which IMNSHO would appear to occur at a perfectly chosen location? Now, given the obvious importance of the function to the argument you're making, how about placing `F(x,i)=\{(y,\mod(i,n)+1): y\in f(x)\}` on a diplayed line by itself?

Comment: Add a group of braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to suppress line breaking in all in-line math formulae in your document, then you can set TeX primitive registers:

```
\binoppenalty=10000 \relpenalty=10000
```

TeX inserts penalty given by `\binoppenalty` after each bin atom and penalty given by `\relpenalty` after each rel atom in the formula. There are no more places where in-line math formula can be broken. If you set these registers to 10000 (prohibit break) then in-line math formula is never broken.